# Add prefix to sql result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add a prefix to a field (ji.issuenum here below), which is decimal(18,0). So that '4' becomes 'PROJECT-4'
As I found from examples, its enough to just add it with +:

```
SELECT 'PROJECT-' + ji.issuenum AS project_id,
       c.cname                  AS component_name,
       pri.pname                AS issue_priority,
       ist.pname                AS issue_status,
       ji.summary               AS issue_summary,
       ji.created               AS created,
       ji.updated               AS updated,
       ji.resolutiondate        AS resolutiondate
FROM   project p
       left outer join jiraissue ji
                    ON ji.project = p.id
       left outer join priority pri
                    ON ji.priority = pri.id
       left outer join issuestatus ist
                    ON ji.issuestatus = ist.id
       left outer join component c
                    ON c.project = p.id
WHERE  p.pname = 'Project'
       AND Year(resolutiondate) = Year(current_date - interval 1 month)
       AND Month(resolutiondate) = Month(current_date - interval 1 month)
GROUP  BY ji.issuenum;
```

But it does not work.
I also tried to cast it to char before I join it:

```
SELECT 'PROJECT-' + Cast( ji.issuenum AS CHAR(20)) AS project_id,
       c.cname                                     AS component_name,
       pri.pname                                   AS issue_priority,
       ist.pname                                   AS issue_status,
       ji.summary                                  AS issue_summary,
       ji.created                                  AS created,
       ji.updated                                  AS updated,
       ji.resolutiondate                           AS resolutiondate
FROM   project p
       left outer join jiraissue ji
                    ON ji.project = p.id
       left outer join priority pri
                    ON ji.priority = pri.id
       left outer join issuestatus ist
                    ON ji.issuestatus = ist.id
       left outer join component c
                    ON c.project = p.id
WHERE  p.pname = 'Project'
       AND Year(resolutiondate) = Year(current_date - interval 1 month)
       AND Month(resolutiondate) = Month(current_date - interval 1 month)
GROUP  BY ji.issuenum;
```

Is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The use of CONCAT in mysql will most likely solve your problem.  It's set to use strings as input and then concatenate them but if you include numerical values it will convert those values to their non-binary string equivalents.  This will work for integers and decimals.

```
CONCAT('PROJECT-',TRUNCATE(ji.issuenum, 0)) AS Project_ID
```

I added the TRUNCATE to the query because I realized you would still get 'PROJECT-4.0' if you had a decimal value of 4.0 for ji.issuenum.  CONCAT doesn't round or trim values it just displays them "as-is" even as a string equivalent.  Truncate(... , 0) will display 0 digits to the right of the decimal.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) is some mysql specific documentation for CONCAT.